# VBA - How to find a string in combobox names?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Some of my combobox names start with "TBSum...".  The objective is to search for all comboboxes that has this string "TBsum" and color those boxes with back_Color and fore_Color.  My code below, doesn't work because I don't know how to write the code for searching a string in combobox names.  Please help?  Thank you in advance.   All these comboboxes are on "MultiPage1.Page6"...

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Enter()

    Dim N As Long
    Dim control_Object As Control

    N = 1
    back_Color = RGB(214, 233, 215)
    fore_Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)

    For Each control_Object In Me.Controls
       If Me.Controls(N).Name = "TBSum" Then
          Me.Controls(N).BackColor = back_Color
          Me.Controls(N).ForeColor = fore_Color
       End If
    Next control_Object

End Sub
```

EDIT

Not working yet, updated code below. The code ran, no errors. But no result.  I have no idea what's wrong. Please help.  (SOLVED:  Updating the code below to correct code... Basically, I needed to add the "For N=1...").  Correct code now:

```
Private Sub ColorCBSum()

    N = 1
    back_Color = &HFFFFC0
    fore_Color = &H62331F
    For Each control_Object In UserForm9.Controls
       For N = 1 To UserForm9.Controls.Count - 1
       If InStr(UserForm9.Controls(N).Name, "CBSum") = 1 Then
          UserForm9.Controls(N).BackColor = back_Color
          UserForm9.Controls(N).ForeColor = fore_Color
          UserForm9.Controls(N) = Format(UserForm9.Controls(N), "#,##0;(#,##0)")
       End If
       Next N
    Next control_Object

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have put your text inside the post. You always can edit your own post. You can add debug code after the IF, to see if it happens, and follow with more debug.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to properly outline my questions and timeline my responses.  I love this forum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
If InStr(Me.Controls(N).Name, "TBSum") = 1 Then
```

Reference : [InStr function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

Comment: Hi Harry - Thank you very much!   Doesn't work yet, probably because my other code is impacting, but I'm working on it, will let you know.  Quick question:  "Me.Controls" covers all comboboxes in the Userform (including comboboxes in MultiPage1) -- right?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Harry - Done, thank you very much for your code!!